# Get Posts with category name, tags and all related in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How to get all posts from DB, with Category, Tags if any, feature_image and other related to post, in one row.

I have this one that gets attachment

```
SELECT 
wp_posts.ID,
wp_posts.post_title AS title,
wp_posts.post_date AS published_at,
wp_posts.post_content AS content,
wp_posts.post_name AS slug,
files.meta_value AS foto
FROM `wp_posts`
INNER JOIN wp_posts attachments ON wp_posts.ID = attachments.post_parent
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta files ON attachments.ID = files.post_id
WHERE files.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
```

Comment: What are you wanting to do with all the data?

Comment: Migrating to new platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I digged more I came up with this query :

```
SELECT  
wp_posts.ID,
wp_terms.name as category,
wp_posts.post_title AS title,
wp_posts.post_date AS published_at,
wp_posts.post_content AS content,
wp_posts.post_name AS slug,
files.meta_value AS foto
FROM
`wp_posts`
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON(wp_posts.ID =     wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON(wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
INNER JOIN wp_posts attachments ON wp_posts.ID = attachments.post_parent
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta files ON attachments.ID = files.post_id
WHERE files.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
```